# My android project is getting "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, android

I have been working on this project for couple of weeks now, and all of a sudden I am getting this `java.lang.NullPointerException`. It's compiling fine. But I am getting this error when I run it.
So I changed the workspace and loaded a previous working version of my project, which I had kept as a backup. And there is the same problem. The app is crashing before loading even the first layout...

Here is my logcat:

```
06-28 20:04:46.428: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
06-28 20:04:46.428: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cloud.mobile/cloud.mobile.MCActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at cloud.mobile.MCActivity.setLoggedIn(MCActivity.java:279)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at cloud.mobile.MCActivity.onCreate(MCActivity.java:198)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-28 20:04:46.542: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more
```

P.S-Today, earlier I played with some String Arrays and dynamically storing in it. That's the first time I received this error..

Comment: clean your build, rebuild your application and try again

Comment: Try debugging it first. The error clearly occurs at cloud.mobile.MCActivity.setLoggedIn(MCActivity.java:279)

Answer (score 4):

Without code it is hard to tell what is going on, but a point to start would be

```
 at cloud.mobile.MCActivity.setLoggedIn(MCActivity.java:279
```

Check line 279 in MCActivity. At that particular line you are trying to operate on "some null value"